How to sent a value from a component to other component and use it on the balde view in livewire?
Hello guys I am working with livewire Components and I am trying to send a dynamic value from one Component to another Component using emit and listeners and I am nothing near the resault I want.
This is My SourceComponent code FormElements.php
class FormElements extends Component
{

    public $willaya;

    
    public function render()
    {
        $destination = DB::table('delivery_fees')->select('*')->pluck('destination');
        return view('livewire.form-elements', compact('destination'));
    }

    public function updateDestination($destination){
        $this->willaya = $destination;

        $this->emit('wilayaUpdated', $destination);
    }
}

$destination this is the dynamic value that's I want to send to another Component.
And this is my DestinationComponent code Form.php
class Form extends Component
{
   public $receivedWilaya;
   protected $listeners = ['wilayaUpdated'];


   public function updatedwilaya($newWilaya)
    {
        $this->receivedWilaya = $newWilaya;
    } 
    
   public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.form');
    }
}

Each time a new destination is selected I want to fetch that new value from FormElements.php send it to form.php then I want to render it on the form.blade.php.
Please feel free to tell me what I have done wrong! and what I could have done to achive my resault
Thanks.

Which version of Livewire are you using? How are the components positioned? (nested, at the same level...). Is it possible to have views too? What problem are you experiencing?

I am using livewire version 2.12 and my components  are at the same level and am getting a null when I try to dd($this->willaya)

Where have you inserted dd($this->willaya) ? Please show also the relevant code of the views
